# How to set an attribute on an element with protractor?

Tags: selenium, angular, webdriver, protractor

I have this snippet that returns an `ElementFinder`

```
const elem = $('[formatcontrolname="startDate"]').$('input');
```

I want to set the attribute `ng-reflect-model` on this element.

Advice for doing this?

I've tried a few `browser.executeScript` commands, but I can't figure out how to leverage the variable `elem`.

---

Edit: I did not end up going this route. I was able to do what I needed using standard css selectors in protractor.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Protractor is for testing the app the way an end user would interact with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing this, this is not what a normal user would do when they are interacting with your app. I'll try to answer the second part of your question

> I've tried a few browser.executeScript commands, but I can't figure
>   out how to leverage the variable elem.

```
var el = element(by.module('header'));
var tag = browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].tagName', el);
```

Copied straight from [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.executeScript)

Comment: Thank you for the link to the protractor api; did not know that existed! For reference, I'm trying to automate clicking this angular 2 module: https://github.com/koleary94/Angular-2-Datepicker. Testing 3rd party angular 2 modules seems tough. Any advice?

Comment: If thats the case, we need to open reproducible issues against selenium. In the meantime did you try using their API? Or temporarily set the attribute using JS, but like I said, its not a great solution.

Comment: You were right. I was able to test by using css selectors. I was able to click the element, bring up the datepicker, find the buttons on the datepicker, and select a date. All using standard protractor selectors.

Answer (score 2):

I set the value of date attribute by following:

```
browser.driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('start-date').setAttribute('value','01/10/2017')");
```

Try this in your scenario, hope this might help.